# Recovering damaged filesystem/partition

Tags: partitioning, partition-recovery, filesystem-corruption

I wanted to increase the size of my /home (originally about 20GB). /home was on the partition /dev/sda9.

There was about 25GB free-unallocated space just after the /dev/sda9 partition. The plan was to expand /dev/sda9 to include this free space and then resize my /home to increase its size (source: Man page of resize2fs).

I expanded /dev/sda9 using `fdisk` while /home was still mounted. Perhaps this is the reason things went wrong? /dev/sda9 is now shown to be about 45GB:

[image].

I attempted to resize using resize2fs but received the following error:

```
guest@kempa:~/$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda9
resize2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda9
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

How can I fix this and recover my /home?

**EDIT:**
I have also tried fsck'ing /dev/sda9 and followed suggestions it spewed, without much success.

[image]

Comment: @Gareth, Thanks for making my question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

e2fsck it first. if not possible, then e2fsck -b 8193 first.

Comment: Tried that before. Doesn't work. Edited the question to include this data.